# Leaflet starting position

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am currently trying to set up a custom map with leaflet using custom tiles. My tile names are the following: (those are all the tiles I have)

[image: Tile Image Names]

Whenever I open my map, I just see a blank space field with the control things. When I open the developer tools I don't see any tiles until I zoom in and out again, the tiles now are e.g. 489,1 etc. which is far from the coordinates of my tiles. The script I currently use for the map is:

```js
var map = L.map('map', { center: [0, 0], zoom: 13 }).setView([0, 0], 0);
L.tileLayer('https://map.******.net/tiles/{x},{y}.png',
  {
    attribution: 'Tiles by <a href="https://******.net">******</a>',
    maxZoom: 17,
    minZoom: 9
  }).addTo(map);
```

Comment: I think you want to use zoom level 0 and `L.CRS.Simple` instead.

Comment: According to [this](https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html), CRS Simple doesn't support multiple tiles though

Comment: I wrote that. It doesn't say that.

Comment: How do I use layers with CRS Simple then?

Comment: Experiment a bit. And be sure of what your coordinate system is.